# combine subtree merge with sparse checkout in git

Tags: python, git

I'm trying to emulate svn:externals in git. In project 'A' I need to pull down library 'B' into a sub folder of 'A'. Both A and B are separate git repos. I know I can do this with either submodules or subtree merge. However, to further complicate things, I need to pull down a subfolder of 'B' into 'A', not the whole project because it is a python module that I need to import directly and I can't have the root directory structure there or it can't be imported.

This is pretty easy to do with svn:externals. With git it seems complicated or even impossible.

Here is an example:

Project B:

```
-B
  - src
    __init__.py
 - test
   ...
```

Project A:

```
- A
   - src
     A.py (imports B)
     - B (partial check of sub folder 'src' as name 'B')
        __init__.py
   - test
     ...
```

Comment: I'm so happy I'm not alone! :)

Answer (score 2):

Git is mostly all-or-nothing. Your best bet is to clone the module elsewhere and either symlink the directory you want, or use `sys.path`.

```
- A
   - src
      - B symlink to ../../B/
- B
```

If you're concerned about size of submodule's clone, and you don't need to commit to it, then you can use `--depth=1` when cloning to ignore history.

Unfortunately, you can't clone a subfolder. At best you could use `git-filter-branch` to delete everything from a repo except a selected subfolder.

Comment: I would like to use the symlink option, but git doesn't seem to respect ntfs junctions. When I do a git add on the junction target, it just tries to add all the files in stead of the link

Comment: @ennui77 AFAIK junctions are hardlinks. Try `MKLINK /D` to create symbolic link.

Comment: Symbolic directory links in windows never seem to really work (explorer doesn't even seem to understand it). The python import system doesn't seem to be able to load symbolic link directories as modules which means I can't use this as a option.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to combine submodules with subtree merge, so first of all add `project B` as a submodule to `project A`, because this will add `project B` as a submodule in the `A/B` directory!

```
cd A
git submodule add <URL to project B>
```

and now perform a subtree merge to include only the desired subfolder of `project B` into `project A`

```
git remote add -f B <URL to project B>
git merge -s ours --no-commit B/master
git read-tree --prefix=A/B/ -u B/master:<path to subfolder>
git commit -m "Merge subfolder from project B into project A"
```

now you can easily update the submodule to the desired commit in `project A`

```
git submodule update --remote
```

you can also do this by a simple Python script, let me show you how:

```
import subprocess

def add_submodule_and_merge(url_to_project_b, path_to_subfolder):
    #step 1:adding project B as a submodule to project A
    subprocess.run(['git', 'submodule', 'add', url_to_project_b, 'A/B'])
    
    #step 2:perform a subtree merge to include the desired subfolder of project B into project A
    subprocess.run(['git', 'remote', 'add', '-f', 'B', url_to_project_b])
    subprocess.run(['git', 'merge', '-s', 'ours', '--no-commit', 'B/master'])
    subprocess.run(['git', 'read-tree', '--prefix=A/B/', '-u', 'B/master:' + path_to_subfolder])
    subprocess.run(['git', 'commit', '-m', 'Merge subfolder from project B into project A'])
    
    #step 3:update the submodule to the desired commit in project A
    subprocess.run(['git', 'submodule', 'update', '--remote'])

#for example you can use it like this :
url_to_project_b = '<URL to project B>'
path_to_subfolder = '<path to subfolder in project B>'
add_submodule_and_merge(url_to_project_b, path_to_subfolder)
```

good luck!

Comment: Hi, nice answer! I tried `git merge -s ours --no-commit B/master` but got an error. I think you need to do a `cd B` first, right? Or something else, perhaps?

Comment: @DaniMesejo Yes, you are correct,before running the command you mentioned, we need to navigate to the directory of `project B`  and this will ensure that we are in the correct directory to perform the merge. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of solving it by tweaking git, why not just install B anywhere, and tell A where to find the submodule to include? If you just add to `sys.path` the folder containing the relevant B submodule, you can go home.

Comment: I like to avoid modifying the sys.path when possible to make easier for other developers to check out code and start working with it. The less environmental setup the better. With the previous svn setup, I was able to check out a project and run it or even deploy it directly without any setup or config

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built-in way in git to do that, you can do it in two steps:

1. in repository `B`, you can "extrude" a history of the `src/` directory:

```bash
git checkout master

# switch to a new branch that will contain this "sub history" 
git checkout -b src-master

git filter-repo --subdirectory-filter src/
```

2. from repo `A`, you can now use `git subtree ...` to include branch `src-master` from repo `B`.

---

`git filter-repo --subdirectory-filter ...` will act in a repeatable way:

if at a later time `B` gets updated, running `git filter-repo --subdirectory-filter ...` on the updated `master` branch will result in a history that updates the `src-master` branch. So you will be able to see what commits are added, `git merge` or `git rebase` will start from the expected merge base, etc ...